# Find size of matrix, without using `size` in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, size

Suppose I want to find the size of a matrix, but can't use any functions such as `size`, `numel`, and `length`. Are there any neat ways to do this? I can think of a few versions using loops, such as the one below, but is it possible to do this without loops?

```
function sz = find_size(m)
sz = [0, 0]
   for ii = m'    %' or m(1,:) (probably faster)
      sz(1) = sz(1) + 1;
   end

   for ii = m     %' or m(:,1)'
      sz(2) = sz(2) + 1;
   end    
end
```

And for the record: This is not a homework, it's out of curiosity. Although the solutions to this question would never be useful in this context, it is possible that they provide new knowledge in terms of how certain functions/techniques can be used.

Comment: I added format debug to my answer.  It's just trivia really, but then that's the point of the question... To try fun/new ideas, right?  :)

Comment: Another possibility: `sz = [sum(m(:,1))/mean(m(:,1)), sum(m(1,:))/mean(m(1,:))];`

Comment: @Robert P. - Yeah, that'll work!  Not exactly efficiently, but definitely effective.

Comment: Very interesting! I suggest the solutions should be ranked in terms of generality (inf, NaN, empty, complex) and speed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a more generic solution

```
function sz = find_size(m)
sz = [];
m(f(end), f(end));
    function r = f(e)
        r=[];
        sz=[sz e];
    end
end
```

Which

1. Works for **arrays**, **cell arrays** and **arrays of objects**
2. Its time complexity is constant and independent of matrix size
3. Does not use any MATLAB functions
4. Is easy to adapt to higher dimensions

Answer (score 3):

For **non-empty matrices** you can use:

```
sz = [sum(m(:,1)|1) sum(m(1,:)|1)];
```

But to cover **empty matrices** we need more function calls

```
sz = sqrt([sum(sum(m*m'|1)) sum(sum(m'*m|1))]);
```

or more lines

```
n=m&0;
n(end+1,end+1)=1;
[I,J]=find(n);
sz=[I,J]-1;
```

Which both work fine for `m=zeros(0,0)`, `m=zeros(0,10)` and `m=zeros(10,0)`.

Comment: @LuisMendo I added a more generic solution.

Answer (score 2):

Incremental indexing and a try-catch statement works:

```
function sz = find_size(m)

  sz = [0 0];

  isError = false;
  while ~isError
    try
      b = m(sz(1) + 1, :);
      sz(1) = sz(1) + 1;
    catch
      isError = true;
    end
  end

  isError = false;
  while ~isError
    try
      b = m(:, sz(2) + 1);
      sz(2) = sz(2) + 1;
    catch
      isError = true;
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Isn't `while` a loop?  ;)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop
(Just friendly banter.)

Answer (score 2):

A quite general solution is:

```
[ sum(~sum(m(:,[]),2)) sum(~sum(m([],:),1)) ]
```

It accepts **empty** matrices (with 0 columns, 0 rows, or both), as well as **complex**, **`NaN`** or **`inf`** values.

It is also **very fast**: for a 1000 × 1000 matrix it takes about 22 microseconds in my old laptop (a `for` loop with 1e5 repetitions takes 2.2 seconds, measured with `tic`, `toc`).

---

*How this works*:

The keys to handling empty matrices in a unified way are:

- empty indexing (that is, indexing with `[]`);
- the fact that summing along an empty dimension gives zeros.

Let *r* and *c* be the (possibly zero) numbers of rows and columns of `m`. `m(:,[])` is an *r* × 0 empty vector. This holds even if *r* or *c* are zero. In addition, this empty indexing automatically provides insensitivity to `NaN`, `inf` or complex values in `m` (and probably accounts for the small computation time as well).

Summing that *r* × 0 vector along its second dimension (`sum(m(:,[]),2)`) produces a vector of *r* × 1 zeros. Negating and summing this vector gives *r*.

The same procedure is applied for the number of columns, *c*, by empty-indexing in the first dimension and summing along that dimension.

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command has a neat option to get the last `K` elements:

> `I = find(X,K,'last')` returns at most the last `K indices corresponding to the nonzero entries of the array`X`.

To get the size, ask for the last `k=1` elements.  For example,

```
>> x=zeros(256,4);
>> [numRows,numCols] = find(x|x==0, 1, 'last')
numRows =
   256
numCols =
     4
>> numRows0 = size(x,1), numCols0 = size(x,2)
numRows0 =
   256
numCols0 =
     4
```

You can use `find` with the single output argument syntax, which will give you `numel`:

```
>> numEl = find(x|x==0, 1, 'last')
numEl =
        1024
>> numEl0 = numel(x)
numEl0 =
        1024
```

Another straightforward, but less interesting solution uses `whos` (thanks for the reminder Navan):

```
s=whos('x'); s.size
```

Finally, there is `format debug`.

Comment: Nice! `find(x|x==0, 1, 'last')` was clever =)

Comment: Isn't using 'find' using a function? ;)

Comment: @gnovice: True enough, but I guess I only explicitly excluded functions similar to `size` in the question text.

Comment: @chappjc Well thought, but how about NaN's or complex values? ;-)

Comment: @Luis Mendo - Good point!  It would need to be `find(x~=0|x==0, 1, 'last')` to deal with `NaN`s and complex values.