# How do nested functions work in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, nested-function

So, I'm [applying for a job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501133/matlab-interview-questions?lq=1) and need to figure out [how nested functions work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2502392/2338750). To be more specific, I would like to know exactly how the following example posted by [gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnovice) works.

The question is:

Given the following function, what will the output be when entering the code below in the command window?

```
function fcnHandle = counter
  value = 0;
  function currentValue = increment
    value = value+1;
    currentValue = value;
  end
  fcnHandle = @increment;
end

f1 = counter();
f2 = counter();
output = [f1() f1() f2() f1() f2()];  %# WHAT IS IT?!
```

<sub>I'm not applying for a job, and I'm able to figure out the answer to the question. I also find [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19284234/2338750) from [Mohsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292374/mohsen-nosratinia) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280117/find-size-of-matrix-without-using-size-in-matlab) intuitive (find the size of a matrix without calling built-in functions). However, I can't help but hearing Albert Einstein's voice in my head.</sub>

[image]

I think the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) was a bit messy, so I would be very happy if someone is able to explain how it works.

Comment: +1 for hearing that in your head! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try....

Each time the function `counter()` its called creates an unique function handle. This function handle is a handle to a function called *increment*, that takes its own variable value, and increments its by one.

So if called twice, like in the code (f1, f2) each time will return the same function (increment) but different handles. You have the function defined TWICE. And each of them now work independently. As this specific function (increment) relies in a saved internal value for its computation, you can observe how if called as in your code sample, outputs [1 2 1 3 2].

A good way of seing the differences better is to redefine the function as:

```
function fcnHandle = counter(val)
  value = val;
  function currentValue = increment
    value = value+1;
    currentValue = value;
  end
  fcnHandle = @increment;
end
```

and calling it like:

```
>> f1 = counter(0);
>> f2 = counter(1000);
>> output = [f1() f1() f2() f1() f2()]  %# WHAT IS IT?
```

Now, you will see that the output is `[1 2 1001 3 1002]`

Makes more sense now?

This code is created so it exploits this attribute of function handles (its the same thing, but its copied twice).

Answer (score 5):

**This** use of nested functions is relevant for memoization (for additional reading see: [use nested functions to memoize costly functions](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/02/08/use-nested-functions-to-memoize-costly-functions)), since it exploits [parametric function handles](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) which store the value of the parameters at creation.

There are two things you need to notice:

1. `counter()` returns a function handle directly to the nested function

   ```
   f1 = counter()
   f1 = 
      @counter/increment
   ```
2. The nested function will 'save' the scoped variables. Refer to [`functions()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/functions.html) for details.

   ```
   s = functions(f1)
   s = 
        function: 'counter/increment'
            type: 'nested'
            file: '\\ic.ac.uk\homes\ok1011\MATLAB\counter.m'
       workspace: {[1x1 struct]}
   ```

   with the scoped workspace retaining:

   ```
   s.workspace{1}
   ans = 
       fcnHandle: @counter/increment
           value: 0
   ```

Basically, `counter()` initializes the `value` to zero, and successive calls to `@counter/increment` will perform `value = value+1;`.

Finally, `@counter/increment` is assigned to `f1` and all `f1()` is doing is `@counter/increment()` on the previously initialized `value`. Initializing `f2 = counter()`, creates another counter with a separate saved `workspace`.

Comment: I like this explanation better.  It shows the internals of what is actually going on. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Neat exercise. I never used nested functions with handles before, so here is my thought process:
I found this paragraph in [the manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html#f4-64094) very instructive:

> Nested functions can use variables from three sources:
>
> ```
> Input arguments
>
> Variables defined within the nested function
>
> Variables defined in a parent function, also called externally scoped variables
> ```
>
> When you create a function handle for a nested function, that handle
>   stores not only the name of the function, but also the values of
>   externally scoped variables.

So in the example, the function `counter` sets the variable `value` to `0` then calls `increment`. `increment` *stores* `value` in its handle, so each time `increment` is called, `value` is incremented and overrides the first definition of `value=0`.

As a result, the output is `0` plus the number of times `increment` is called, which is each time a given instance of `counter` is called.

When you write this:

```
f1 = counter();
f2 = counter();
```

You create two separate instances of the function `counter` which will increment independently.